# Android login registration with postgresql

Tags: android, postgresql

New to android. Just wondering if there are any tutorial on user login registration authentication for android with postgresql db.

There seems to be tuts with mysql, sqlite, and php, would love to stick with just java on the server side of things for authentication.

I believe to get up and running with postgresql you have to utilize http and JDBC driver, but would love a walkthrough with files to reference so I can learn.

Want to utilize heroku for the android app and know that postgresql is the best fit for this build.

Answer (score 1):

In the android app side the default database must be used which is SQLite and for the server side if you want to use postgresql , you can use it. I dont think it should create any problem.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter which database you use. Android connects using webservices that you create which act as bridge between database and Android. I suggest you to use any [REST services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) .